# QMdiArea: window menu in system default language

Tags: qt4

I have a QMdiArea with subwindows. Each subwindow in KDE (just like top-level windows of all applications) has a standard menu with actions like "hide", "restore" etc. This menu appears when you click on the window icon in the top left of the window. However, the subwindow's menu is always in English while normal windows have the menu in the operating system's default language.
Is it possible to make Qt translate this menu to another language?